# how do i read a .dxl file in R using read.csv?

Tags: r

I tried opening the file in excel and it is being displayed in proper format. Now how do i read it in R? I tried using read.csv function. It takes all the columns together without any separator.

Comment: It might help if you define what your dxl file is. Is it the lotus notes DXL as vrajs5 suggested in his answer or a winlab data file or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly load it to dataframe, first you have to load it as xml and then you can process it further.

Try following

```
require(XML)
data <- xmlParse('sample.dxl')
xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
```

You this list further to make your dataframe.